# ASP.NET - Transmit File and Response.End appending 'Thread was aborted' to file contents

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have an ASP.NET webpage that generates a file and returns it after the user submits a form;

However the file contents are being modified when sent by ASP.NET.

The code is below:

```
        Response.TransmitFile(fileName)
        Response.[End]()
```

This causes the file contents to contain this text at the end of it -

> Thread was being aborted.

This corrupts the file, as it's contents are encrypted and are read by an application later on.

Is there a way for me to send a file after a user clicks a button in ASP.NET without it causing this file corruption?

It's not something I can store permanently and link to, it's generated based on user input on the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ending the response generates an error.  Wrap the response.end in an error handler like so:

```
try
response.end
catch ex as System.Threading.ThreadAbortException
 ' do nothing

end try
```

Comment: It looks like I had a try catch in the calling method somewhere else that was sending the caught exception through response.write(); This helped me figure it out. Thanks!